# What does the idiom "If I didn't have bad luck I'd have none at all" mean?

Tags: idioms

I've heard this idiom when something bad happens to someone.

What is this saying trying to convey and how it is doing that?

Comment: It's nonsense really, as 'having no luck' is used as a synonym for 'having bad luck'. It's tongue-in-cheek, and acceptable as such. It's just a wry way of claiming that you only ever get bad luck (whatever luck might be interpreted as).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It means the person only ever has bad luck.**

If they didn't have bad luck, they wouldn't have *any* luck, because they never get good luck (or any other kind of luck).